# Office 365 not parsing the mail content in attachment properly

Tags: grails, jakarta-mail, office365

I am sending a meeting invite using Grails mail service. The calendar is sent as an ics file (attachment) and also as a multipart of type text/calendar. When I try to open the mail in Office365, I am getting the attachment as "unable to verify organizer.ics". To solve this problem, it was suggested that both the organizer and the mail sender username in the Config has to be same.

Due to design constraints I cannot make both the Organizer and the From Email address same. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Note: The mail is working perfectly in Outlook, Gmail and other mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a security requirement where the sender has to have the same email address to avoid fishing and spams. just add the sender username as your organizer.

hope this helps.